# Can I require that pull requests to a certain branch on github be squashed?

Tags: github

Github has the option to allow a PR to be squashed when merged ("Squash and Merge")

**Is there anyway I can configure the branch so it only allows the "Squash and Merge" option?**

My scenario is this

- we have a `develop` branch, that feature requests are pushed to
- sometimes developers will forget to choose "Squash and Merge" and will commit their feature branch, with 10-20 tiny commits to the develop branch.
- These changes eventually get merged to master, and feature history becomes hard to read

I have looked in hooks in branch protection rules, but didn't see any such option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the option to change what type of PR merge is available on Github is set on a per repo basis. Since PRs are a github thing, not a git thing, I can't think of a way that you'd be able to do anything with githooks either.

I don't see a great option for your workflow as long as you require the intermediate develop branch that eventually gets merged into master. Workflows that have multiple layers of PRs get messy on Github. The one real option would be that you require squash to merge on Github PRs and then the regular merge from develop to master happens outside a PR (could be local on a machine or via a Github action potentially).

But, your best option if this is really a big problem may be to modify your workflow. One common workflow would be that master *is* the development branch. Then when it is time for a release a release branch or tag, depending on your needs, is created from master. The you will have no issue turning on the repo wide requirement for squashing.